# Monitor open process files on Linux in real-time

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, process, files

The files opened by a process can be found with this command:

```
ls -l /proc/PID/fd
```

Is there any way that can be done in a more interactive way like [`tail`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), auto-refreshing every x seconds?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the nice [`watch`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) command:

```
watch -n 10 ls -l /proc/$$/fd
```

You could use an old school while loop:

```
while:
do
 ls -l /proc/$$/fd
 sleep 10
done
```

`watch` is in the [`procps`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/procps) package on Debian-based systems and the `procps` RPM on Red Hat-derived systems.

Comment: sleep itself can be used as condition in while loop, so your example can be written more elegantly like this:

while sleep 10; do ls -l /proc/$$/fd; done

Answer (score 14):

If you want to see each file as it is being opened, you can filter that with `strace`. For example:

```
strace -p _pid_of_app_ -e trace=open,close
```

Comment: This _really_ is the best answer. I'd recommend the flags `-y` and `-f` if you're attempting to debug something running in a shell. Just pass the shell PID in and `-f` will follow any forks.

Answer (score 6):

You could combine `lsof`and `watch`.

For example `watch "lsof -p 1234"` will give you a list of all open files of pid 1234 every 2 seconds. You could change some parameters to meet your needs.

Comment: it will not give a list EVERY 2 seconds. The parameter -r 2 is missing for that to work! -p is the PID. The answer is very poor!

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of the `-r` option for `lsof`. Therefore I used `watch` to execute `lsof` every two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I created a bash file where I was writing the output of the command to a file. File was generated on the basis current date. Here I am counting number of open files.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
 cd /proc/<PID>/fd
 today=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
 filename="/tmp/${today}.txt"
 ls -l | wc -l >> "${filename}"
 sleep 10
done
```